# Copy file from sd card and past it to EditText with thumbnail in android

Tags: android

I have implemented a custom keyboard in android and want to send music files from that keyboard. I want to implement functionality to copy and paste music files from sdCard to EditText with thumbnails like TextEFX app in IOS. Here is the link for demo for TextEFX app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plUNf3DZgaM
I do not want to share only copy and past like TextEFX app. Can anyone tell me how to implement exactly the same as TextEFX app?

Thanks in Advance